# Validate some file input fields with jQuery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

HTML

```
<div id="multadpic">
    <input type="file" name="adpic[]" />
</div>
```

I have a button after this div that i can add infinite file inputs, like this:

```
<div id="multadpic">
    <input type="file" name="adpic[]" />
    <input type="file" name="adpic[]" />
    <input type="file" name="adpic[]" />
    <input type="file" name="adpic[]" />
    <input type="file" name="adpic[]" />
</div>
```

How would i validate it using jQuery validate plugin? Considering that i can't write square brackets in the rules, but the name of the input has square brackets..

One solution that i found is to write my own validation after the plugin (but i don't know if it'd work or if it's a crappy work around):

```
jQuery('#myForm').validate(
{
    rules:
    {
        //my rules
    },

    messages:
    {
        //my messages
    },

    submitHandler:
    {
        //my file input validation
    }
});
```

I've been reading a lot of questions about this but no answer resolved my need.

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: What type of validation are you trying to do? Why can't you escape the brackets?

Comment: I need to validate the file extensions, accepting just 'jpg|jpeg|png' and the file size. Is it possible to escape the brackets? I didn't know about that..

Comment: To escape the brackets use `\\[` instead of `[` and `\\]` instead of `]`

Comment: It doesn't work, Batman.

Comment: The brackets do not get escaped.  The whole `name` simply gets enclosed in quotes, `"adpic[]"`.

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets are not a problem for the `.validate()` plugin.  You must simply enclose the `name`, containing special characters, in quotes.

**Working Demo**:

http://jsfiddle.net/grVmG/

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            "field[]": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "field[]": {
                required: "this is required",
                minlength: "must be at least {0} characters"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
 <input type="text" name="field[]" />
```